# Laravel extract excerpt from content using tinymce

Tags: regex, laravel, expression

I'm using tinymce as rich text editor and separate excerpt from content via pagebreak button that insert a `<!-- pagebreak -->` tag . I'm wondering what is the best way to extract excerpt from database.
I know i can use `preg_math` as well as `preg_split` , but is it realy best and optimized solution?

wouldn't it be better and faster to save excerpt in a separate column?

Comment: Just to be clear: TinyMCE editor has a pagebreak button, user clicks it and then inserts that HTML comment at the cursor's current position. You want to be able to take a variable containing this content, `$content`, and retrieve everything _before_ `<!-- pagebreak -->`?

Comment: yes,but im looking for an optimized and fast solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, without using any regex functions:

```
$pagebreak = '<!-- pagebreak -->';
$content = 'I am the excerpt<!-- pagebreak -->I am the rest of the content';

$excerpt = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, $pagebreak));
$restOfTheContent = substr($content, strpos($content, $pagebreak) + strlen($pagebreak));

var_dump($excerpt);  // string(16) "I am the excerpt"
var_dump($restOfTheContent); // string(28) "I am the rest of the content"
```

Please note that this is really only designed to work with a *single* page break.  It wouldn't be too difficult to modify it to generate an array of `$pages` based off of the string `$content` should multiple page breaks be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. its also good to check excerpt lenght     `return strlen(trim($excerpt))? $excerpt : $content;`

Comment: Sure, that would be beneficial in case no `<!-- pagebreak -->` is found, or perhaps just fallback to a simple `strlen(...)` call if you need to have a guaranteed smaller excerpt of content available for design reasons